# Would be okay to drive on this tire?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

I have a set of new wheels and tires coming in 2 weeks. Would it be okay to drive on this tire for 2 weeks? It seems like it's holding air fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMRhx.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I can barely see any damage. There's three things which I use as guidelines for sidewall damage:

1. Is the tire still holding air?
2. Can you see the sidewall cording behind the damage?
3. Is there any bulging of the tire at the site of the damage?

If none of these hold true, you should be in pretty good shape. Considering you have new wheels/tires coming in a couple of weeks, I don't think I'd worry too much about it. Just keep an eye on it for the three things mentioned above. If any of them become prevalent, change it out with your spare tire.

Comment: Gotcha. I actually went to a tire shop to ask them about it, and they said it shouldn't be a problem at all.